# Unity UI-обрезка под маску

Tags: unity3d, ui

У меня есть мини-карта(raw image), как обрезать её(и не только, например ещё другие изображения) по контуру.
Пытался делать что-то с Mask но не получилось.
Вот пример(карта и контур):
[image: Вот пример]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hierarchy`

```
GameObject [Canvas]
    GameObject [Mask, Image] (Image - спрайт маски)
        GameObject [Raw Image]
```